# Gatsby google-tagmanager plugin: how to access dataLayer.push

Tags: gatsby

I have installed and configured the gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager in my site, and I can record pageviews with no issue.

But I also need to track button clicks by doing a dataLayer.push in an onClick event. I am not seeing a way to give the onClick event of an element access to the dataLayer object.

It either gives me an error that dataLayer is undefined, or that gtag is undefined.

Any syntax on this would be appreciated.

Gatsby-config

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager',
  options: {
    id: 'GTM-XXXXXXX',
  },
}
```

Function called on button onClick

```
handleButtonClick=()=>{ 
  dataLayer.push({event: 'Request Button Click'});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
handleButtonClick=()=>{ 
  window.dataLayer.push({event: 'Request Button Click'});
}
```

Also, by default in development, the GTM script will not be run. That means `window.dataLayer` will be undefined.

Comment: so if window.dataLayer is undefined then how will I develop and test my tracking on local without getting errors?

Comment: options: {
        id: process.env.GTM_ID,
        includeInDevelopment: false,// change this to true
      },